# thymeleaf syntax for variable from spring model to be used in noscript

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Syntax for retrieving the spring model values in noscript using thymeleaf

[[${gtmUrl}]] is working fine within script tags but not for noscript

Is there a different syntax

In java controller the gtmUrl attribute is set

```
model.addAttribute("gtmUrl", "http://test.com");
```

In html,

```
<noscript>
        <iframe src="[[${gtmUrl}]]"
            height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

try using **th:src="${gtmUrl}"**,

```
 <noscript>
     <iframe th:src="${gtmUrl}" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<noscript>
        <iframe src="[[${gtmUrl}]]"
                height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

to:

```
<noscript>
        <iframe th:src="${gtmUrl}"
                height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
```

*How it is working?*

**You can access variables value by ${key}.**

*Example*

```
model.addAttribute("key", value);
```

Get value by `${key}` in HTML

> In Thymeleaf, these model attributes (or context variables in
>   Thymeleaf jargon) can be accessed with the following syntax:
>   `${attributeName}`, where attributeName in our case is `stream`. This
>   is a Spring EL expression. In short, Spring EL (Spring Expression
>   Language) is a language that supports querying and manipulating an
>   object graph at runtime.

[Thymeleaf Document](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
 <noscript>
            <iframe src="[[@{gtmUrl}]]"
                height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe>
        </noscript>
```

here i use `@` sing instead of `$`

Comment: thanks for you help, the above solution by tharanga-dinesh worked for me